# Were Elladan and Elrohir twins?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

The answers to [Were any of the Elves in Tolkien twins?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46358/were-any-of-the-elves-in-tolkien-twins) include Elladan and Elrohir as twins. Is there any canon sources backing this up? Wikia is a dreadful source for Tolkien canon, is it stated anywhere that the sons of Elrond are twin brothers?

Comment: @WadCheber this is a specific question asking for clarification on something commonly stated without evidence

Comment: This is why we can open bounties asking for canonical sources. You're basically asking "Are the answers to this other question right?".

Comment: @WadCheber I can't open bounties. No option?

Comment: You could open a bounty on the original question.  Anyone can.

Comment: @WadCheber how? There's no option? Is this a website only thing?

Comment: https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5736/21730255580_29c30e66f8_b_d.jpg

Comment: https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5748/21730370298_d563673018_z_d.jpg

Comment: @WadCheber yeah. I'll have to start using the web. It's not available of the iPhone/iPad apps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appendix B:

> **130** Birth of Elladan and Elrohir, sons of Elrond.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Appendix B "The Tale of Years" *(ii) The Third Age*</sub></sup>

Of course this doesn't preclude the possibility that one was born early in the year and one was born late, as sometimes happens with human children, but writings in *Morgoth's Ring* debunks this notion; the Elvish gestational period is twelve months:

> A year passed between the begetting and the birth of an elf-child, so that the days of both are the same, or nearly so.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* X *Morgoth's Ring* Part 3: "The Later Quenta Silmarillion" Chapter 2: "The Second Phase" *Laws and Customs Among the Eldar*</sub></sup>

Comment: This becomes dangerous when dealing with various versions of the legendarium. My understanding is History of Me is a full history and contains conflicting versions? Also Elrond was half-man ;)

Comment: @CarlSixsmith Generally yes, but the essays in *Morgoth's Ring* are later and more stable writings, and typically viewed with some authority by Christopher Tolkien. The issue of Elrond being half-elven is more complicated, but Elves and Men are biologically identical; the differences in this case are spiritual, rather than physiological

Comment: @JasonBaker: if they're biologically identical, then the period of gestation can't possibly be different, and vice versa. So which is it?

Comment: @Martha Both, with the understanding that Tolkien is not really interested in the finer points of biology. From the man himself (talking about immortality, granted, but the principle is the same): "I do not care. This is a biological dictum in my imaginary world. It is only (as yet)
an incompletely imagined world, a rudimentary 'secondary'; but if it pleased the Creator to give it
(in a corrected form) Reality on any plane, then you would just have to enter it and begin studying
its different biology, that is all."